# javascript: How to hide or remove element using raw javascript like google keep?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create [google keep](https://keep.google.com/) input text, when I clicked inside input text, input title and button create are showing, how to hide them back when I click outside input text?

heres' my version :

```
    <input type="text" class="input-style target" style="display: none;" name="input-title" placeholder="TITLE">
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="inputNote" class="input-style" name="input-note" placeholder="note">
</div>
<div class="btn-action">
  <button class="btn-style target" style="display: none;">CREATE</button>
</div>
```

more visit:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fadlystwn/nb2eppu0/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for:

```
inputNote.onblur = function removeContent() {
  for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    target[i].setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nb2eppu0/7/

You can find more info about this event here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

**EDIT:**
As you commented, you also need the possibility of writing in the title input and also be able to click the button, I've implemented this surrounding all the HTML with a form tag and using this one to check the focus of the elements and the blur.

When a children node of this form is focused it will set the *showingContent* as true, maybe you have doubts about the timeout in the blur function; this is simple, the blur is executed before the next focus, so, when an element is blurred it will set the *showingContent* variable as false but, if the new focus is on another children item of the parent form, as I said before, this variable will become true and, in the next cycle the timeout function will be executed.

Here is the final fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nb2eppu0/8/

Comment: hello Horus, thanks for answering my question, I think it works but, I still can't get the title input, it's still hiding when I tried to type something on it.

Comment: @FadlySetiawan I modified my answer with a new fiddle and an explanation of what I made to achieve what you're looking. I hope you understand it. Sorry for my bad English >_<

Comment: Hi Horus, I really excited and satisfied with your answer, thank you so much its help me a lot with clear explanation.. thanks a lot buddy.,